# Regular expression to normalise swedish currencies

Tags: c#, .net, regex, localization

I'm currently making a regular expression on the c# engine with the goal of stripping currency letters from XML that contains Swedish currency.

A version of all of the possible values that can appear in the XML document look like this :

`Value="-0.00SEK" Value="-5.60SEK"  Value="SEK5.60"  Value="5.60"`

Please note, if the number is negative, currency lettering will be appended onto the end.

I have constructed this regex
`Value="((A-Z{1,3})?|(\-)?)(\d*\.\d*)(\D{1,3})?"`.

replacing with the value   `Value=\"$1$4\"`.

which outputs the following:

`Value="-0.00"    Value="-5.60"    Value="SEK5.60"    Value="5.60"`

The negative number cases work well but I don't know why/how to do the positive cases as it's still printing SEK at the start. I'm trying to remove this so it just shows as `5.60`.

rextester : http://rextester.com/PYTKG15831

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Should be `[A-Z]` and you need `$3$4` for the replacement.

Comment: Put into square brackets : ([\-+])

Comment: Replace `SEK` with empty string?

Comment: ClasG what do you mean? I've you're suggesting multiple parses then I would rather not.

Comment: Check http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=SEK&i=-0.00SEK%0d%0a-5.60SEK%0d%0aSEK5.60%0d%0a5.60&r=. Check the "Context" tab.

Comment: @ClasG As i said, these values are in a large xml file. Thus SEK could appear elsewhere so that answer doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the RegEx [`Value="[A-Z]{0,3}(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[A-Z]{0,3}"`](https://regex101.com/r/jcHVeY/2).

Replace with `Value=\"$1\"`.

- `Value="` matches `Value="` litterally
- `[A-Z]{0,3}` allows for three uppercase letters before your price
- `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` captures your price (with our without the `-`)
- `[A-Z]{0,3}` allows for three uppercase letters after your price
- `"` matches `"` litterraly

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/jcHVeY/2)

Comment: I've run this and it works very well thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You might also use 2 positive lookbehinds `(?<=` using an alternation `|` to match the 3 uppercase characters and replace with an empty string:

[`(?<=Value="\-?\d+\.\d+)[A-Z]{3}(?=")|(?<=Value=")(?:[A-Z]{3})(?=\d+\.\d+")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dValue%3d%22%5c-%3f%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b%29%5bA-Z%5d%7b3%7d%28%3f%3d%22%29%7c%28%3f%3c%3dValue%3d%22%29%28%3f%3a%5bA-Z%5d%7b3%7d%29%28%3f%3d%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b%22%29&i=Value%3d%22-0.00SEK%22+Value%3d%22-5.60SEK%22++Value%3d%22SEK5.60%22++Value%3d%225.60%22)

- `(?<=Value="\-?\d+\.\d+)[A-Z]{3}(?=")` Assert that what is on the left is for example `Value="-0.00`, then match 3 uppercase character and assert that what is on the right is a `"`
- `|` Or
- `(?<=Value=")(?:[A-Z]{3})(?=\d+\.\d+")` Assert that what is on the left is for example `Value="`, match 3 uppercase characters and assert that what follows is `5.60"`

[Test](http://rextester.com/HAVVK74377)